# How to find value of $y$ when slope and $2$ points are given but $1$ set of points is missing $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find the value of $y$ when slope and $2$ points are given but $1$ set of points is missing $y$?
I am given $(10, y)$ and $(25, 100)$ with a slope of $m = -5$.

I tried using point slope formula by doing $y-y=-5(x - 10)$ but I got a function back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, let's try your method.

For point slope, it might be useful to utilize the point you are already given, which is $(25,100).

Then, we have $y-100 = -5(x-25)$.

Then, we can plug $(10,y)$ in.

We have $y-100 = -5(10-25)$ to get $y = -5(-15)+100=175$.

So the point is $(10,175)$.

Comment: Okay the problem was is that I didn't plug (10, y) in after solving with the points given.

Answer (score 1):

By the formula $$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{100-y}{25-10}=-5$$ we get
$$100-y=-5(25-10)$$ or $$y=100+5(25-10)=100+175=175$$

Comment: +1 for deriving point slope from the slope formula

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Comment: The other answer where y = 175 is what I was looking for but this works if I was trying to find point slope formula.